# Linq to Entities with two tables

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

When you are writing a linq query that involves two tables/entities for which you have already defined the relationship in your entity framework data model, do you have to define the join in the query or is there a different syntax that uses the already defined relationship?

```
var q =

    from c in categories

    join p in products on c equals p.Category into ps

    select new { Category = c, Products = ps };
```

Otherwise what is the point of defining the relationships in the EF model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If things are set up correctly you'll have a reference property that represents the foreign key relationship, in which case you should be able to do something like:

```
var q = from c in categories
        select new {Category = c, Products = c.Products};
```

Comment: I have a navigation property setup between my 2 entities, but the relationship is 1 > 0..1 and when I try to write any type of linq query involving the two it is throwing an error message which says "Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'". Am I doing something wrong, reading around the error it has been suggested to use the entity reference, but I don't know if this is true?

Comment: @suggy1982 Can you post an example of the LINQ query in your question?

Comment: the entities are different from my original question, suppliers entity is PK & the DirectSupplier entity isFK.I want to return  suppliers who are direct suppliers. VS is underlining "s.DirectSupplier", with the error "An expression of type 'TransactionScopeTest.DirectSupplier' is not allowed in a subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<TransactionScopeTest.Supplier>'.  Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'"

            var q = (from s in db.Suppliers
                     from d in s.DirectSupplier
                     select d);

Comment: @suggy1982 So you have a one to many association between Suppliers and DirectSuppliers, but you don't have a reference property so you can just do a query like "var q = from s in db.Suppliers select s.DirectSupplier"?

Comment: Yes the relationship is a one to many and yes there is a reference property. I just got the syntax wrong. The syntax you provided worked. Thanks :-D

Answer (score 2):

You should have a navigation property in your Category entity called `Products`, which contains all related Product entities, you should use this instead of doing a manual join.

Comment: Thanks I will check the setup in my model.

Comment: I have a navigation property setup between my 2 entities, but the relationship is 1 > 0..1 and when I try to write any type of linq query involving the two it is throwing an error message which says "Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'". Am I doing something wrong, reading around the error it has been suggested to use the entity reference, but I don't know if this is true?

Answer (score 2):

I find this blog post [**join in LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities Considered Messy, Redundant**](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/) explains the concept very clearly.